# Updating VCL from the same thread that created the UI. Why?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, thread-safety

I know that I must call Synchronize to update the vcl from a thread that did not create the controls or send a message to the window.

I have often heard the word not thread safe but I can't find an actual explanation about what is happening.

I know the application might crash with an access violation, but again I don't know why?

Please shed a light on this topic.

Comment: There used to be a little explanation in the [docs](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/threadsusingthemainvclthread_xml.html). Somehow I can't find anything similar in the current [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/How_To_Build_Multithreaded_Applications).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

About GDI thread safety in Windows, [see this reference article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684256(v=vs.85).aspx).

It clearly states that you can **access safely** handles from multiple threads, *but* that it should not be made at the same time. You need to protect access to GDI handles, e.g. using critical sections.

Remember that GDI handles, like most Windows handles, are *pointers* of internal structures mapped to an `integer` (`NativeUInt` under newer Windows, for 64 bit compatibility). Like always in multi-thread computing, accessing the same content concurrently can be source of problems, which are very difficult to identify and fix.

The UI part of the VCL itself was never meant to be thread-safe, from the beginning, since it was relying on the non-thread-safe Windows API. For instance, if you release a GDI object in a thread, which is still needed in another thread, you'll face potential GPF.

Embarcadero (at this time) could have made the VCL thread-safe, serializing all UI access via critical sections, but it may have added complexity, and decreased overall performance. Note that even Microsoft .Net platform (in both *WinForms* and *WPF*) also requires a dedicated thread for UI access, AFAIK.

So, to refresh UI from multiple threads, you have several patterns:

1. Use `Synchronize` calls from the thread;
2. Send a GDI custom message (see `WM_USER`) from the background threads to notify the UI thread that a refresh is needed;
3. Have a *stateless* approach: the UI will refresh its content from time to time, from the logic layer (using a timer or when you press some buttons which may change the data).

From my point of view, I prefer option 2 for most UIs, and an additional option 3 (which can be mixed with option 2) for remote client-server access. Therefore, you do not have to want from the server side to trigger some update event to the UI. In a HTTP/AJAX [RESTful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959851/using-rest-with-delphi) world, this does definitively make sense. Option 1 is somewhat slow, IMHO. In all cases, options 2 and 3 expect a clear [n-Tier layered architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture), in which logic and UI are not mixed: but this is a good pattern to follow anyway, for any serious development.

Comment: "It clearly states that you can access safely handles from multiple threads, but that it should not be made at the same time." It does not say that. So long as your access is read-only then multiple threads can simultaneously access GDI, window properties etc. When talking about thread-safety it is pointless being imprecise. The term thread-safe is meaningless on its own, as Eric Lippert pointed out: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx

Comment: You are right, from the technical POV. I was taking in account the fact that accessing a GDI handle is mainly to send messages to him, and potentially allocate and release associated resources (font, pen...). My advice/rule was made to ensure that access was safe, by discouraging simultaneous access, especially via the VCL layer. Sending messages to GDI instances *is* thread safe, but allocating/releasing GDI resources AND setting parameters is not - this is what was written. You could be able to mix GDI commands by mixing messages, and it may have an unexpected behavior. So "one at a time".

Comment: See also Remy's comment here: [What does the VCL is not threadsafe really mean?](http://borland.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.vcl.components.using.win32/200610/0610063192.html).

Comment: Java's various frameworks have only a single thread that can access the UI as well.  It's pretty much universal.

Answer (score 12):

One of the biggest causes of the thread-unsafety in the VCL UI controls is the `TWinControl.Handle` property getter.  It is not just a simple read-only accessor of the control's `HWND`. It also creates the `HWND` if it does not exist yet.  If a worker thread reads the `Handle` property when no `HWND` exists yet, it creates a new `HWND` within the worker thread context, which is bad because `HWND`s are tied to the creating thread context, which would render the owning control pretty much inoperable at best since Windows messages for the control would not go through the main message loop anymore.  But worse, if the main thread reads the same `Handle` property at the same time the worker thread does (for instance, if the main thread is dynamically recreating the `Handle` for any number of reasons),  there is a race condition between which thread context creates the `HWND` that gets assigned as the new `Handle`, as well as a potential handle leak potential if both threads end up creating new `HWND`s but only one can be kept and the other gets leaked.

Another offender to thread-unsafety is the VCL's `MakeObjectInstance()` function, which the VCL uses internally for assigning the `TWinControl.WndProc()` non-static class method as the message procedure of the `TWinControl.Handle` window, as well as assigning any`TWndMethod`-typed object method as the message procedure of the `HWND` created by the `AllocateHWnd()` function (used by `TTimer` for example).  `MakeObjectInstance()` does quite a bit of memory allocating/caching and twiddling of that memory content which are not protected from concurrent access by multiple threads.

*If* you can ensure a control's `Handle` is allocated ahead of time, and *if* you can ensure the main thread never recreates that `Handle` while the worker thread is running, then it is *possible* to safely send messages to that control from the worker thread without using `Synchronize()`.  But it is not advisable, there are just too many factors that the worker thread would have to take into account.  That is why it is best that **all** UI access be done in the main thread only.  That is how the VCL UI system is meant to be used.

Answer (score 4):

Windows controls with handles are not thread-safe (i.e. they cannot be accessed safely by two different threads at the same time), and Delphi wraps the Windows controls to give you the VCL controls. Since the controls ARE accessed by the main GUI thread, you need to leave them alone if you are executing another thread.

Comment: It's more complex than this. By and large the Windows API is thread safe. Window properties can be read from multiple threads simultaneously. Modifications should confined to the thread with which the window has affinity.

Comment: @David, yes, I'm sure that's correct, but lets face it, the simplest way is to assume only single threaded access. What you could conceivably do and what is practical to do are often two different things ;-)